# LIKE function for user-defined characters

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm building a test to highlight data with illegal characters, where illegal chars are user-defined.

So I have something like

```
SELECT col
FROM db
WHERE col LIKE '%[^<legal chars>]%'
```

Usually, when `<legal chars>` contains a special character, I can use `ESCAPE`.

However, here **`legal chars` can be anything** (for example, `a-zA-Z0-9` and/or `^`, `[`, `\`, `*`), so no matter what special char I choose, it might be in `legal chars`.

Does anyone have an idea about how I should approach this question?

Comment: What is `a-z` supposed to match?  Three characters or any lowercase?

Comment: Any lowercase @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions, don't use `like`.  Use `regexp`:

```
where col regexp $whatever
```

I would suggest that you construct the regular expression on the client side.  But you can do it in MySQL as:

```
where col regexp concat('[', $whatever, ']')
```

However, you need to be careful about regular expression special characters, such as `\` and `-`.